# How to pass VM arguments to tomcat maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have an integration test module that deploys the project WAR file to an embeded tomcat server by using the below config in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
        <path>/helloworld</path>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-tomcat</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. When I usually deploy the app manually to tomcat via IDE's "Edit Configurations", I specify some VM arguments. How can I specify those **VM arguments** to the embeded tomcat server when I do a **mvn verify**?
2. When my project has many modules out of which one of them is the integration test, I try to fire up tomcat using the similar pom entry, how to specify **which WAR to deploy**?

Answer (score 1):

To specify system properties, you can use the [`systemProperties` configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#systemProperties) like in [this example](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html).

```
<configuration>
    <systemProperties>
        <example.value.1>alpha</example.value.1>
        <example.value.2>beta</example.value.2>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

To deploy a specific war to Tomcat, you can use the [`deploy` goal](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) and specify the file using the `warFile` configuration.

```
<configuration>
    <warFile>${project.build.directory}/someFile.war</warFile>
<configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @SilverNak

The system properties worked. However, specifying the war file is not working; it is still deploying the module where the pom file resides;
I want to deploy another war file. Below is my configuration:

 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>9090</port>
                    <warFile>/Users/asdf/Desktop/myApp.war</warFile>
....

Am i missing something?